# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping in NET 6 web app

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this error `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.` in this line

```
var marketingEventEntity = _mapper.Map<MarketingEvent?>(request);
```

But I already configured it in my AutoMapperProfile. Here is the class

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CreateMarketingEventRequest, MarketingEvent?>();
    }
}
```

Below is the full code. I am using Mediatr and CQRS pattern.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateMarketingEventRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var query = new CreateCommand(request);
            var result = await _mediator.Send(query);
            return CreatedAtAction(null, new { id = result }, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Problem(ex.Message);
        }
    }

public class CreateCommand : IRequest<MarketingEvent>
{
    public CreateMarketingEventRequest createMarketingEventRequest { get; set; }

    public CreateCommand(CreateMarketingEventRequest createMarketingEventRequest)
    {
        this.createMarketingEventRequest = createMarketingEventRequest;
    }
}

public class CreateHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateCommand, MarketingEvent?>
{
    private readonly IMarketingEventService _marketingEventService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CreateHandler(IMarketingEventService marketingEventService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _marketingEventService = marketingEventService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<MarketingEvent?> Handle(CreateCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var marketingEventEntity = _mapper.Map<MarketingEvent?>(request);
        if(marketingEventEntity == null) return null;
        return await _marketingEventService.Create(marketingEventEntity);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the models (MarketingEvent, CreateMarketingEventRequest ) ...

Comment: could you show how you configure automapper? You should really give a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this:

```
var marketingEventEntity = _mapper.Map<MarketingEvent?>(request);
```

Be:

```
var marketingEventEntity = _mapper.Map<MarketingEvent?>(request.CreateMarketingEventRequest);
```

Comment: Did try to put this in the comments above, but the formatting was horrible